Redirect using server hooks not working in SvelteKit
I am creating an application in sveltekit, trying to protect my routes through the use of hooks or middleware, but when I am logged in and try to enter an unprotected route, I want to redirect to the /home address, however I get an error and no I understand what I'm doing wrong
I have this hook in sveltekit.
hooks.server.js
import 'dotenv/config';
import { redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
const unProtectedRoutes = ['/', '/registro', '/registro/pn','/registro/pj','/forgotmail','/forgot'];
const SECRET_KEY = process.env.SECRET_KEY;


export const handle = async ({ event  , resolve}) => {
    console.log(event.url.pathname);
    console.log(process.env.SECRET_KEY);
    const token = event.cookies.get('access_token');
    console.log(token);

    
    if (!token && !unProtectedRoutes.includes(event.url.pathname)) {
        console.log('NETRE pIRMERRRRRRRRRRRRR IF');
        redirect(303, '/');
    }

    if (token) {
        try {
            console.log('NETRE SEGUNDOOOO IF');
            // Verificar el token
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, SECRET_KEY , { algorithms: ['RS256'] } );
            console.log(decoded);
            //const userId = decoded.id;
            if (event.url.pathname === '/logout') {
                console.log('entre logoutF');
                event.cookies.delete('access_token', { path: '/' });
                redirect(303, '/');
            }
            if (unProtectedRoutes.includes(event.url.pathname)) {
                console.log('SI esta en la');
                redirect(303, '/home');
               
            }

        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error al verificar el token:', error);
            event.cookies.delete('access_token', { path: '/' });
            redirect(303, '/');
        }
    }
    


    return resolve(event);
};

For some reason in this "if" an error occurs, and it fails to redirect to the route "/home", finally this error is caught by my try/catch , and it ends up redirecting me to the route "/"
         if (unProtectedRoutes.includes(event.url.pathname)) {
                console.log('SI esta en la');
                redirect(303, '/home');
               
            }

I have tried using Response, but it doesn't work the way I want
return new Response(null, {
                    status: 303,
                    headers: {
                        location: '/home'
                    }
                });


It will be easier to help you if you tell us what the error message is. But redirect() should be thrown, and you're not doing that, so maybe that's the problem.

I'm 99% sure it's because everything is within a try block. redirect throws an error which is captured by SvelteKit and redirected. In your code, your redirect calls are catched and never thrown from the hook function. What you need to do is check if the error is a redirect. If so, throw it. SvelteKit has a built-in function called "isRedirect"
Code:
import { isRedirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';

try {
  // ... your code ...
} catch (error) {
  if(isRedirect(error)) throw error; // <-- add this
  console.error('Error al verificar el token:', error); 
  event.cookies.delete('access_token', { path: '/' });
  redirect(303, '/');
}

